# Sybase-IQ : Query with join returns always 0 rows (but count(*) give rows)

Tags: sql, select, rdbms, sap-iq

I have a very strange comportment on my Sybase IQ database.

I have 2 tables :

**Table A** : 47 000 000 rows

**Table B** : 497 rows

If I make the following query :

```
select count(*) from A
inner join B on A.ID = B.ID;
```

The result of the count is **5 661 188**.

If I make the following query :

```
select * from A
inner join B on A.ID = B.ID;
```

The result is **0** row !

If I make the following query :

```
select A.field1 from A
inner join B on A.ID = B.ID;
```

The result is **5 661 188** rows.

```
select A.field2 from A
inner join B on A.ID = B.ID
```

The result is **0** row !

I execute these queries with Interactive SQL (Sybase Central).

I've tried also to execute these same queries with the ETL Talend, and i got same results as above.

Any ideas why we have these very strange results ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Results OK when I change the option JOIN_PREFRENCE. Probably a problem with this version of Sybase IQ (15.2).
See here : http://scn.sap.com/message/15605021